# Derivative of convolution is convolution of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

When $f,g \in L^1(R)$ and $g$ is differentiable with $g' \in L^1(R)$, I want to show that $$(f*g)'=f*g'$$ holds. I guess that the proof should be something like this.
$$\begin{align}
(f*g)'(x) &= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \{(f*g)(x+h)-(f*g)(x)\}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \{\int_R f(y)g(x+h-y)dy-\int_R f(y)g(x-y)dy\}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}  \int_R f(y)\frac{g(x+h-y)-g(x-y)}{h}dy\\
(*) &= \int_R f(y)\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{g(x+h-y)-g(x-y)}{h}dy\\
&= \int_R f(y)g'(x-y)dy\\
&= (f*g')(x)\\
\end{align}$$

However, in order to take the limit inside the integral, we need to show that there exists $\delta>0$ and $h \in L^1(R)$ s.t.
$$|f(y)\frac{g(x+h-y)-g(x-y)}{h}|\leq h(y)$$ holds.

Is the above condition sufficient to find the appropriate function $h$? We have $g'\in L^1(R)$ so my guess is that $h$ should be expressed as a function of $g'$. I can create a pointwise bound on the difference quotient of $g$, but without further assumption I can't seem to find the uniform bound on the difference quotient. Any help, comment or counterexample is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is easier to integrate since $\int$ is a bounded linear map $\int_0^x f \ast g'(y)dy = f \ast \int_0^x g'(y)dy = f \ast (g(x)-g(0)) = f \ast g(x) + C$

Comment: @reuns Hmm,, interesting approach. But doesn't $g$ have to be absolutely continuous in order to invoke the second equality regarding fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: You said $g'$ is $L^1$. The point is that $\int$ is bounded linear map on $L^1$